# How to reformat my SQL Server Query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

I have written an SQL Query that brings the result in below format

```
ResourceName    ProjectName  TaskName Timesheet Period  ActualWork  TimeByDay  DayName

    Jim Carry        Project A   Task A   2011-12           40        09/10/2011  Monday

     Jim Carry        Project A   Task A   2011-12           70        09/10/2011  Monday
     Jim Carry        Project B   Task A   2011-12           80        09/12/2011  Tue.
     Perth S.         Project A   Task A   2011-12           35        09/10/2011  Mon.
```

I want to write the query so that it gives me something like;

```
ResourceName    ProjectName         TaskName         Timesheet Period  Monday Tue  
Jim Carry           Project A        Task A            2011-12          110    80
```

As you can see that the new columns is created in second query name as Monday, Tuesday and so on. Plus the total is also calculated based on day and hence result of Monday column is 40+70 while of Tuesday is of 80+0.

Below is the query that brings the code snippet 1

```
DECLARE @startdate DATETIME
DECLARE @enddate DATETIME

SET @startdate='1/1/2011'
SET @enddate='12/31/2011'

SELECT TOP 100 [IR.TimesheetProjectHoursByDay].ResourceName,
               [IR.TimesheetProjectHoursByDay].ProjectName,
               [IR.TimesheetProjectHoursByDay].TaskName,
               [IR.TimesheetProjectHoursByDay].PeriodName + ' ' + '(' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR, [IR.TimesheetProjectHoursByDay].PeriodStartDate, 101) + ' - ' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR, [IR.TimesheetProjectHoursByDay].PeriodEndDate, 101) + ')' AS [Timesheet Period],
               [IR.TimesheetProjectHoursByDay].ActualWork,
               [IR.TimesheetProjectHoursByDay].TimeByDay,
              DATENAME(dw,TimeByDay) as [DayName]
FROM   [IR.TimesheetProjectHoursByDay]
WHERE  [IR.TimesheetProjectHoursByDay].TimeByDay >= @StartDate
       AND [IR.TimesheetProjectHoursByDay].TimeByDay <= @EndDate
       AND [IR.TimesheetProjectHoursByDay].[Project Departments] LIKE N'CSENG'
       AND [IR.TimesheetProjectHoursByDay].ActualWork > 0
       AND [IR.TimesheetProjectHoursByDay].ResourceName LIKE '%Jim%'
GROUP  BY [IR.TimesheetProjectHoursByDay].TimeByDay,
          [IR.TimesheetProjectHoursByDay].ResourceName,
          [IR.TimesheetProjectHoursByDay].ProjectName,
          [IR.TimesheetProjectHoursByDay].TaskName,
          [IR.TimesheetProjectHoursByDay].[Project Departments],
          [IR.TimesheetProjectHoursByDay].ResourceStandardRate,
          [IR.TimesheetProjectHoursByDay].PeriodName,
          [IR.TimesheetProjectHoursByDay].PeriodStartDate,
          [IR.TimesheetProjectHoursByDay].PeriodEndDate,
          [IR.TimesheetProjectHoursByDay].ActualWork
ORDER  BY [IR.TimesheetProjectHoursByDay].TimeByDay DESC
```

Can you please suggest me what change i need to do in the SQL Query so that i can get the result as mentioned in code snippet 2?

Let me know for any inputs required. Please find test data sheet that make things look more clear at [here](https://skydrive.live.com/redir.aspx?cid=d2c4a58bc07faf1f&resid=D2C4A58BC07FAF1F!116&authkey=sJCgVkozve0%24)
Please guide!

Thanks!

Comment: Doesn't this give incorrect results though as your query is still attributing 110 hours to task A when they were in fact split over task a and b in the original result set.

Comment: Thanks Moose. I have now modified my result set.

Comment: Moreover, even if it was for Task B, it really didn't matter because what we need to calculate is total hours worked for Jim Carry irrespective of the task he works on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correct you can try this:

```
create table #tbl (ResourceName varchar(100), ProjectName varchar(100), TaskName varchar(100), ActualWork int, TimeByDay date)

insert into #tbl values    ('Jim Carry','Project A','Task A',40,'20111009'),
('Jim Carry','Project A','Task A',70,'20111009'),
('Jim Carry','Project B','Task B',80,'20111209'),
('Perth S.','Project A','Task A',35,'20111209')

select ResourceName,ProjectName, year(TimeByDay), MONTH(TimeByDay),
       sum(case when datename(weekday, TimeByDay)='Monday' then ActualWork else 0 end) Monday,
       sum(case when datename(weekday, TimeByDay)='Tuesday' then ActualWork else 0 end) Tuesday,
       sum(case when datename(weekday, TimeByDay)='Wednesday' then ActualWork else 0 end) Wednesday,
       sum(case when datename(weekday, TimeByDay)='Thursday' then ActualWork else 0 end) Thursday,
       sum(case when datename(weekday, TimeByDay)='Thursday' then ActualWork else 0 end) Thursday,
       sum(case when datename(weekday, TimeByDay)='Friday' then ActualWork else 0 end) Friday,
       sum(case when datename(weekday, TimeByDay)='Saturday' then ActualWork else 0 end) Saturday,
       sum(case when datename(weekday, TimeByDay)='Sunday' then ActualWork else 0 end) Sunday
from #tbl
group by ResourceName,ProjectName, year(TimeByDay), MONTH(TimeByDay)

drop table #tbl
```

You can also use [PIVOT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx) as CJM suggested.

Comment: Just be aware that the original query shown takes in dates as variables. It could theoretically report on a years worth of data (that's a lot of Mondays). I'd suggest getting the total hours per day, and then work out a better way to display the data (maybe by date).

Comment: @Igor, thanks for the query. That really helped in creating a columns naming from Mon-Sun. But what if i need to sum up the values based on Period Column? So i am getting three rows for Monday as 2,1 & 8 for same time period (2011-12). I need to add and bring up the values as 11. Same goes for Tue-Sun

Comment: @Xorpower Sorry, I cannot get what do you mean: 'I need to add and bring up the values as 11'? Do you need to group them by year?

Comment: I need to group them by "Period" column. But if tasks are different, i don't think that would work

Comment: I have uploaded Test Data File (from test db) to make things look more clear. Visit https://skydrive.live.com/redir.aspx?cid=d2c4a58bc07faf1f&resid=D2C4A58BC07FAF1F!116&authkey=sJCgVkozve0%24

Answer (score 0):

Given you suggest that it didn't really matter as you are only after the total number of hours worked by resource on a given day you could try something like (**Note**: This is untested, but just an example);

```
SELECT TOP 100 [IR.TimesheetProjectHoursByDay].ResourceName,
[IR.TimesheetProjectHoursByDay].TimeByDay,
SUM([IR.TimesheetProjectHoursByDay].ActualWork) OVER(PARTITION BY [IR.TimesheetProjectHoursByDay].TimeByDay) AS "Total Hours"
```

And then utilise this as a derived table from which to organise by days. There was a great [post on Window functions](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/window-functions-in-sql-server/) on the simple talk website recently. Take a read through. It is enlightening.

Comment: @Moose: Your query brings up the summation but not the columns as Mon-Sun

Comment: As I suggested on Igor's post, I can't see that you desire to output by day name is going to be easy to read. Your query example above extracts a years worth of data. So I think you need to edit your question to state more clearly the output you are chasing. Do you intend to show a years worth of data all summed up under 7 dayname columns-  Monday through Sunday? If this is the case they you could adjust my query to partition by ResourceName and use that as a derived table inside Igor's query below. Note Igors groups by ProjectName too. I'd assumed you didn't require that.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you could use [PIVOT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx) for this; take a look at [this example](http://www.simple-talk.com/community/blogs/andras/archive/2007/09/14/37265.aspx).